# How to remove accents (diacritic)?

Tags: expl3, accents, latex3, l3regex

I'm trying to convert some strings with accented letters. I'd like to be able to remove only the accent marks  while keeping the letters. (E.g. convert ô to o, so Hôspital would become Hosiptal).

What is the best method for achieving this?

I can do it like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N  \l_accented_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_replace_all:nnN { neN }
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \g_my_seq { é , è , ê , à , â , ô , ö, î , ï , ç , É , È , Ê , À , Â , Ô , Ö , Î , Ï , Ç }
\prop_const_from_keyval:Nn \g_my_pl  {
    é = e , è = e , ê = e ,
    à = a , â = a ,
    ô = o , ö = o ,
    î = i , ï = i , ç = c , 
    É = E , È = E , Ê = E ,
    À = A , Â = A ,
    Ô = o , Ö = O , 
    Î = I , Ï = I , Ç = C }

\NewDocumentCommand{\remove}{ m }
 {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_accented_tl { #1 }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_my_seq
      {
        \regex_replace_all:neN { ##1 } { \prop_item:Nn \g_my_pl { ##1 } } \l_accented_tl
      }
    \tl_use:N \l_accented_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\remove{Hörmander}, \remove{Hôspital} 
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to achieve this with somthing like

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_accented_tl { #1 }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { (é)|(è)|(à)|(ç) } { (?1:e)|(?2:e)|(?3:a)|(?4:c) } \l_accented_tl
\tl_use:N \l_accented_tl
```

or better?

Comment: Presumably you mean "Hôspital would become *Hospital*". However, I'm a bit confused because "Hôspital" isn't the correct spelling, but the circumflex indicates an <s> was removed, so perhaps you mean "Hôpital" becomes "Hospital"?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Thank you :-).

Answer (score 6):

If you're using pdflatex, then it's very simple: just redefine (locally) the accent macros to be no-ops.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removeaccents}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\'\@firstofone
  \let\`\@firstofone
  \let\^\@firstofone
  \let\"\@firstofone
  % add the other accent commands you need
  #1
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\removeaccents{Hörmander}

\removeaccents{Hôpital}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Oh, by the way, “Hôspital” is wrong: it's either “Hospital” or “Hôpital”. The famous marquis used the latter spelling.

Comment: This is even better. But still curious, in regex_replace solution.

Comment: @studentmaths In pdflatex `ô` is actually two byte…

Comment: i didn't undestande what you mean.

Comment: For my  real need this is exactly what i want, however, the aim of my question
is to understand `regex_replace` so i am really sorry. What i want is replace a set of letters
one by one (the case of accented letters is also is also interesting because of the particularity).
Should i edit my question? ask new one?

Comment: (1) For string replacement, `\tl_replace_all:Nnn` is much faster, and "replacing letters" is just string substitution; (2) composite glyphs, like `o`+`^`, are also strings, so you will need two checks: `o`+`^`>`o` and `ô`>`o`; (3) `\regex_replace_all:nnN` can be used for *patterns*, e.g., replace `\r{A}` - which typesets `Å` - with `A`, and the pattern could be: `\r{`*<any letter>*`}`. (4) For regex, as exercise, do a replace all `\textit{...}` with, say, `{\itshape ...}`; (5) Regex can do (`ô`) or (`o`+`^`) > `os` in 1 step, `replace` function would need 2 steps.

Comment: There is also the tricky bit: `A`, `Α` and `А` are three different letters, Latin, Greek and Cyrillic. Guess what happens on the various Wikipedia pages dealing with translieration to/from Cyrillic-using languages? And then there are possibilities like Cyrillic `A` + combining diacritical mark acute accent, which makes it look French, `Á`, when it is not Basic Latin.